# Программирование перемещения курсора

Tags: c, borland

Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо написать программу на Borland С, что бы выводился массив в окошко, а нажимая на стрелочки я мог по нему бегать и что-нибудь печатать в определенном месте. Массив я вывожу, теперь борюсь с функцией `gotoxy`.

Это мой убогий код. Жалкая попытка выполнить действие перемещение курсора вверх.

```
while (z != 'z') {

    ch = getch();
    if (ch == 27) {
    z = 'z';
    }
    if (ch == 38) {
    while (i != 1) {
        i = i + 1;
        gotoxy(1, i);
    }
    }
    if (ch == 39) {
    }
    if (ch == 40) {
    }
    if (ch == 37) {
    }
    putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, а в чём проблема? Что работает не так, как ожидалось? Кстати, зачем вам `gotoxy` в цикле, разве нельзя сразу "прыгнуть" на нужное значение?

ЗЫ: Подумайте о том, что случится, если вы захотите вывести символ в последнюю позицию последней строки.

Comment: Я если нажимаю стрелку вверх (переместиться на позицию выше) то он ее вводит как букву! и никаких действий не происходит. А ну по идее и в цикле должно сработать)) если так то.... Но согласен его нужно убрать.
что значит прыгнуть на нужное значение? необходимо что бы я мог как угодно пользуясь стрелками перемещаться.... не одноразово....
вы очень продуманный человек) но про последний символ это не важно))) мне бы что бы хоть как то заработала)) а gotoxy обсепечивает перемещение по окну с текстом! сам препод подсказал подскажите как правильно этим пользоваться прошу!!!!

Comment: я думаю, Вам нужно воспользоваться библиотекой "Turbo Vision" и не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: у меня такое задание изобрести велосипед! неужели никто не знает даже примерно как это можно сделать с помощью gotoxy?
блин да я не прошу решать скажите примерно что должно быть!!!  и как это должно выглядеть.....

Comment: вообще у меня есть библиотека где эти x и y прописаны и как они должны действовать! могу скинуть поглядеть!! мне надо просто подсказать как это должно быть в коде!! к какой переменной что плюсовать что бы сдвинуться на шаг по стрелке! и как это вообще должно выглядеть....